# How to put a html link from local folder in xml?

Tags: xml

I have a question, how to put a html file from local map in to a xml.
This is a example:

```
    </page>`<page title="Youtube Video" src="yt1a.jpg" zoom_enabled="false">
        <area rect="4%,76%,435,155"/>
        <video src="pubs/book3/pages/Zapad/_flash/Virtual360Studio & Carlo_BeliManastir-Zapad" still_second="35" controls="yes" padding="50" resize_mode="fit"/>
        <element><![CDATA[<p>pubs/book3/pages/Zapad/_flash/Virtual360Studio & Carlo_BeliManastir-Zapad</p>]]></element>

    </page>`
```

Thanks for understanding!
NeveN

Comment: can you explain more? Do you want to map the html elements as xml? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: The example in the question appears to have placed some HTML in an XML document. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that it won't show in browser. This id a html I like to be shown in the book Virtual360Studio & Carlo_BeliManastir-Zapad. The path to it is pubs/book3/pages/Zapad/_flash/Virtual360Studio & Carlo_BeliManastir-Zapad. So what do I do wrong. Thanks!

Comment: I just gues, is the problem in src? Everything is ok, images, txt, swf video, but that html path is the problem. Should I try to put an online html insted an offline? I need it to be offline html, but if it's ipossible I'll try something else.  Thanks all!

Comment: Why should it show in a browser? It's just a piece of data in an XML file. If you want it to show in a browser, then you would generally need to transform it into HTML first.

Comment: Why should the "HTML path" do anything? It is a paragraph with a text node in it. If you want to write HTML that will load some HTML into another document, then you would use an iframe, not a paragraph. You'd also use a real URL (which would require escaping special characters).

Comment: The html is a virtual project in my pc. Xml is the broushure. So I was thinking that there is something to put that html project in the xml broushure. This is the link of the project: http://poslovne-zone.beli.manastir.carlo-it.hr/index.php?option=com_wrapper&view=wrapper&Itemid=87  Is it possible to put him in the xml broushure? The same project is in the pc but offline, and he works. Thanks Quentin!